# min and max value from php array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6];
$min = min($array);
$max= max($array);
```

- I want min as 1 and max as 6 i don't want to consider 0 as min with
  php array.

Comment: You'll have to remove `0` from the array. I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: Simplest solution: remove 0 from the array before calling `min`.  Other solutions would involve writing your own custom version of `min`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) to filter the zero out of the array

```
$a = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6);

$a = array_filter($a);

$min = min($a);
$max = max($a);
```

Comment: array filter will do it without such a function

Comment: That works indeed, but array_filter already filters out 0, as that's converted to the boolean false. So the custom function should not be necessary.

Comment: Great answer +1, but I think if in the future he wants to change the limit to get min as 2, or whatever.

Comment: @Márcio when that time comes, `array_filter` is still the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

> Use array_shift for 0 and array_pop for last